# WPF Application is slow / jerky whilst being moved

Tags: wpf, performance, redraw

I have a rather basic shell of a WPF app that I am creating.  When I move it using the `DragMove()` function the app moves properly but seems to "jerk" a lot.  It seems to me that the redraw rate is very low making the application look slow and unresponsive.

Currently there is no "code" besides a call to `DragMove()`.
The XAML consists of an outer border with rounded corners and drop shadow set to `RenderingBias="Performance"`.  There is also a small gradient on the title bar and a path. But even commenting these out of the code still makes the app appear jerky and slow whilst moving.

Note I have ran this in Release and outside the debugger too.

Comment: What's the value of `RenderCapability.Tier`? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx

Comment: Great idea - it is set to `2` though so looks like I have full rendering on the video card?

Comment: Next thing I would try then is Wpfperf tooling. It will tell you what is being rendered with hardware acceleration, and possibly point out where the time is going. I think it's in the SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6B6C21D2-2006-4AFA-9702-529FA782D63B&displaylang=en), though it has tended to be hard to track down at times. Good luck!

Comment: By the way, if you create a brand new WPF project, add the simplest possible `DragMove` stuff, and run in release mode, do you get the same problem?

Comment: If I take it back to simply a white rectangle with nothing else in there (commented out) it still occurs.... I have an ATI Radeon HD 4350 - this should surely be enough to run most windows apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience, try removing the drop shadow and you'll see much better perfomance.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/99faecec-395f-4a47-92ee-620b11c39ae7

Comment: Try setting AllowsTransparency to False on your main window and have a normal bordered window.

I know this is not exactly the kind of solution you want but it will atleast give some pointers on where the problem lies.